# Add DataGridViewComboBoxCell to GridView c#

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

Seems like it's so simple but for some reason working on it last 4 hours with no result.
I have simple Gridview with  two columns and few rows already filled, now I want to add ComboBoxCell to the next row.

I'll show my logic and maybe you'll show me my error:

```
SampleGridView.Rows.Add("test1", "test1");
SampleGridView.Rows.Add("test2", "test2");
SampleGridView.Rows.Add("test3", "test3");
```

works fine for three rows now I am inserting my ComboBox:

```
DataGridViewRow RowSample = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewComboBoxCell  CellSample = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
CellSample.DataSource = StringList; // list of the items that I want to insert in ComboBox
RowSample.Cells.Add(CellSample);
SampleGridView.Rows.Add(RowSample);
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Sorry man, I think that it was in ASP.NET. It is WinForms right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out :) I was trying to insert ComboBox to the second cell of the row, and it didn't work. I was trying to do it like this:

```
SampleGridView.Rows.Add("CellText", RowSample);
```

but it actually have to be like this

```
DataGridViewRow RowSample = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewComboBoxCell  CellSample = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
CellSample.DataSource = StringList; // list of the string items that I want to insert in ComboBox
CellSample.Value = StringList[0]; // default value for the ComboBox
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
cell.Value = "CellText"; // creating the text cell
RowSample.Cells.Add(cell);
RowSample.Cells.Add(CellSample);
SampleGridView.Rows.Add(RowSample);
```

Comment: This is the reason I hate Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combo.datasource = stringlist;

SampleGridView.Columns.Add(combo);
```

This is off the top of my head but should work.

Comment: this adds combo box to the column but not to the specific row

Comment: Are you wanting to have a different datasource for each row?

Comment: basically only one row have to be ComboBox, all others just text rows