# Putting a listbox/dropdown menu in a data grid view C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a data table in a data grid view. I want to put an listbox/dropdown menu in a specific column and row. I have tried this but it doesn't work --

```
var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView[1, 1].Value = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

Here is how I populate the table--

```
public DataTable createGridForForm(int rows, int columns)
{              
    // Create the output table.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add("column " + i.ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        // populate data row with values here
        ListBox test = new ListBox();
        myTabPage.Controls.Add(test);
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return table;
}
```

And here is how I create the datagridview.

```
private void createGridInForm(int rows, int columns)
{
    DataGridView RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createGridForForm(rows, columns);

    //DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[0];
    //ID_Column.Width = 200;

    int positionForTable = getLocationForTable();
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Size = new Size(995, 200);
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Location = new Point(5, positionForTable);
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right on track with your first code block... the problem was you were trying to add a column to a cell reference. If you want to add a column where all rows have a drop down, then do exactly what you were doing, but simply add the column instead of specifying a cell value, like this:

```
var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

Then, specify the datasource as you normally would for a combobox.

Alternatively, if you want a specific cell to have a different combobox, or only a single cell in the column to have one, you can create a separate one as shown [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8f8612ce-e467-463b-851c-a9084541fbf9/different-data-sources-in-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-for-each-row?forum=winformsdatacontrols) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468684/add-datagridviewcomboboxcell-to-gridview-c-sharp).

Edit: To add a combobox to a specific cell in the DataGridView, you would do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

            // add some columns and rows
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell c = new DataGridViewHeaderCell();
                dgv.Columns.Add("Column" + i, Convert.ToString(i));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgv.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
            }

            //create a new DataGridViewComboBoxCell and give it a datasource
            var DGVComboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

            DGVComboBox.DataSource = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};
            DGVComboBox.Value = "one"; // set default value of the combobox

            // add it to cell[4,4] of the DataGridView
            dgv[4, 4] = DGVComboBox;

            // add the DataGridView to the form
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please help me, i have looked for the answer for 5h now. i want a specific cell to have a combobox. Can you help me with the code

Comment: i tested it but my grid view disappeared from the form :(

Comment: can you add: 
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView[1,1] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

to your post's code just after you assign the datasource in createGridInForm()? that should give you an empty drop down in the [1,1] cell, and confirm that it will work.